# How to create a script using wgrib2 command

Tags: grib, grib-2, bash

I have several model data with the following format

`postwrf_d01_YYYYMMDD_INIT_f00000.gr2`

where `INIT` = `0000`, `0600`, `1200`, `1800`, each consisting of up to several hours of forecast (`f00000` to let's say `f08400` with a six hourly interval).

Inside this `gr2` data are multiple variables.

Now using `wgrib2` utility, I can select just the variables I want using the following command

`./wgrib2 postwrf_d01_20131107_0000_f00600.gr2 -match ':((U|V)GRD:10 m above ground|PRMSL|(ABSV|HGT|UGRD|VGRD|TMP):(850|700|500) mb):' -grib OUT.gr2`

How can I create a bash script from the above wgrib2 command? I want the OUT.gr2 to have the following file formats.

1) d01_YYYYMMDD_ZZZZ_f0HHHH.gr2 
2) YYYYMMDD_ZZZZ_f0HHHH.gr2 
3) nwp.TC23.YYYYMMDDZZ.f0MMMM.gr2

For example
     input file : postwrf_d01_20160521_1800_f08400.gr2 
    outfile shoud be 
1) d01_20160521_1800_f08400.gr2
2) 20160521_1800_f08400.gr2 
3) nwp.TC23.2016052118.f05040.gr2 ( 84 hr is 5040 min.)

Comment: So you want three output files (identical except for the specified filename) for each input file?

Comment: What does your bash script so far look like?